# Unexpected error on UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, pingdom

I'm trying to access the [Pingdom API](https://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation-rest) in Google Apps script following that example:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/external_apis

```
query = 'credits';
var username = 'foo';
var password = 'bar';
var credentials = username+':'+password;
var url = 'https://'+credentials+'@api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/'+encodeURIComponent(query);
var headers = {
  "App-Key": "abcd",
};
var options = {
    "method": "get",
    "headers": headers,
    'validateHttpsCertificates':false
};
Logger.log(url);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

The code execution breaks with the below error:

> Unexpected error: https://foo:bar@api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/credits
>   (line 17, file "Code") Dismiss

If I copy/paste the above URL into a browser it works (i.e. I'm getting a "Missing application key" from the pingdom API which confirms username and password where properly provided, otherwise you get an Invalid Credentials error). I tried with and without `encodeURIComponent` on `credentials` and I get the same error. `'muteHttpExceptions':true` doesn't help either.

**Any idea what could cause the error?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that including login information in the URL is causing an error in UrlFetchApp. Please file a bug in our [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). In the mean time, put the login information in the Authorization header and it should work correctly.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + password)
  }
});
```

Comment: Issue raised (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2859). Unfortunately, `Pingdom`'s implementation of `HTTP` Basic seems poor: testing with curl, when the credentials are provided in the `URL` is works, when provided via the `Authorization` header, the `API` returns a `User credentials missing` error (which is therefore where I'm suck with the Google Apps script as I can't use the credentials in the `URL`).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problems trying to access the Gitlab API in Google Apps Script. As mentioned in the accepted answer, including login information in the URL causes an error. The Basic Authorization method in the accepted answer did not work for me in Google Apps Script either. Modifying the authorization header to the 'Bearer' type did the trick.

```
var url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/" + projectId;
var options = {
  'headers' : {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually in my case was very simple:

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob();
```

this was the error line:

Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 500. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
cpOnePdfAndRep  @ CP 1 PDF AND REP.gs:37

and it was simply because the sheets that the PDF file was exported from were hidden,
just in case.