# Shopify authentication using the google app script Class OAuthConfig

Tags: api, google-apps-script, shopify

I am trying to connect with my shopify shop through the google javascrip. The schema for authentication should be something similar to the one you can find on google documentation for twitter. I'am trying the following code, but I always get the error:{"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}

```
function getInfofromshopify() {
var handle = "01-02-0316_cmt_utensili"
var urljson ="https://mysitename.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?handle="+handle;
var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("shopify");
oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://mysitename.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token");
oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://mysitename.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token");
oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://mysitename.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize");
oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(API_KEY);
oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(Shared_secret);
var options =
{
"oAuthServiceName" : "shopify",
"oAuthUseToken" : "always"
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urljson,options);
var responsestr = response.getContentText();
var result = Utilities.jsonParse(responsestr)
}
```

Comment: Were you able to call the Shopify API from another programming environment with the same credentials? That will help us understand whether there is an Apps Script issue here or if something is actually wrong with your credentials.

Comment: Can you also apply the API tag to get the question visible to anyone watching for that?  I tried but the edit was rejected for being too minor.

Comment: Added API tag. The credential looks to be correct because if you try to acces with the siple URL: https://API_KEY:Shared_secret@mysitename.myshopify.com/admin/products.json?handle=01-02-0316_cmt_utensili it works. I tried to put the url in this format into the argument of UrlFetchApp.fetch but I got an error.

Comment: I find a solution for my issue even if it does not reply to my original question, but for the meanwhile I can go with the solution suggested in the article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773678/unexpected-error-on-urlfetchapp-fetch-in-google-apps-script

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
var url = "https://<YOUR_SHOP>.myshopify.com/admin/products.json";
var username = "<YOUR_SHOPIFY_API_KEY>";
var password = "<YOUR_SHOPIFY_API_PASSWORD>";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"method":"get", "headers": {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)}});
```