# Importing Excel Spreedsheet with external site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't know whether this is good place to ask such question but I help need to know is it possible to get excel data from a site which have login credetials and in that in a specific tab to get updated excel data.

Site is like this way: **(Example)**

www.abc.com/Login

I enter my login credetials and after that I go to specific tab such as Export Data tab then I select the criteria then I click on Download Report.

I wanted to have is to update google spreedsheet to that updated report. Is it possible to do via google script?

If this question should not be posted then please let me know I will delete it rather than to downgrade this post. If this should not be posted then please guide me with the other external site where I can post this question and get help as I badly need help with this.

Other than that if you have question or any clarification please ask.

Extended Description

Let's say I have a site

Steps:

1. Go to the site (Example: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)
2. Assume that you have to login to that site
3. After login to to the tab call Basic Initialisation
4. You land on that page, on that page you have some drop down list which you select and then you click on export excel.
5. The excel file which can be exported that excel I would like to import to my google drive if possible via Manage Version.

Comment: Firstly, does the abc site have an api to do what you are suggesting? If yes, then all you need to do is make a UrlFetch call to get the data. Secondly, in opinion, this question needs a code you tired and more specifics on the website you are trying to get the data from to be viable quesiton in this forum.

Comment: In In addition to the idea @JackBrown provieded regarding an API. If that is not possible, are you willing to manually save the report in a Google Drive folder and then have a script open that and retrieve the data? It could delete the file once done or move it to another folder.  Others may have other ideas.  One way or another it is possible. The intention here is to try some code and ask for help when needed, providing sample code, etc.

Comment: If I had the knowledge then I would have added my script but I don't have knowledge regarding that that is the reason I asked without adding any code. Currently I am doing manually to import data.

Comment: @JackBrown It's a web API with a login credential to get to that page. Is it possible do it in google script?

Comment: Based on the document, [Eternal APIs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) can interact with APIs from all over the web. You can try authenticating Urlfetch using OAuth 2.0 or Authorization header to authenticate a request. See related SO post - How to use [UrlFetchApp with credentials? Google Scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718759/5995040) and [Unexpected error on UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16929517/5995040). Hope this helps.